# When would I be interested in a function of the parameter $\theta$ (i.e. $g(\theta)$) vs only $\theta$?

Tags: estimation

Let $\theta$ be an unknown parameter that describes the distribution of the data $X$. In the following sense:

$$ X \sim P_{\theta} $$

I was learning about estimators and found the following quote on theoretical statistics book written by Keener

> For now we focus on estimation, in which the goal is to find statistic $\delta$ so that $\delta(X)$ is close to $g(\theta)$. Then $\delta$ or $\delta(X)$ is called an estimator of $g(\theta)$.

The thing that confuses (or maybe I have never seen an example), why or when would I ever be interested in a function of the parameter $\theta$, i.e. $g(\theta)$?

I do see that $g(\theta)$ is more general, but I don't see when I'd be interested in a function of the parameters. It seems that $\theta$ is sufficient to specify $X$, so why would I want to change it with g?

Answer (score 3):

Example: your data is drawn from a gamma distribution, and you want to know its mean. The gamma distribution has two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (or $\lambda$ and $\mu$, or $k$ and $\theta$, or whatever), but you're not really interested in those, as they have no relevance to your scientific or practical needs. So in this case, $g$ is the particular function that gives the expected value from the distribution's parameters, say

$$g(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha/\beta \text{, or}$$

$$g(k, \theta) = k\theta$$

In both cases, your $\delta$ would simply be the sample mean,

$$\delta(X) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i$$